# Typesetting + sign as if a letter

Tags: math-operators, kerning, text-mode

In Baxter's transcription of Middle Chinese, there is an ASCII-friendly version, which uses only te 26 Latin letters as well as a + sign (standing for ɨ). Assume I wish to typeset specifically this ASCII-friendly scheme (so as not to frighten the readers with the IPA-ish convensions, say). Clearly, the result is abysmal. it goes above the line, below the line, is much thinner then the rest, and the kerning is questionable:

[image]

So, how would I get out of this conundrum? How should I typeset a plus sign that it harmunozed with the surrounding letters in height, thickness, and kerning (or at least in kerning)? (Clearly, sending the whole segment to \texttt works, but it is not something that one would do for possibly thousands of reconstructions in a text.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `jw+j` the + comes from the same font as jw and is not given any math space so whether it looks good or abysmal is just down to the artistic choice of the font designer. Just choose a font you like, some possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

jw+j

{\sffamily jw+j}

{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes} jw+j}

{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Heros} jw+j}

{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Pagella} jw+j}

{\fontspec{EB Garamond} jw+j}

{\newcommand\+{\raisebox{.7pt}{\tiny\bfseries+}} jw\+j}

\end{document}
```

The last one shows a possibility if you want to stick with latin modern, and just change +